# Need help with javascript unchecking of one checkbox unchecks the main checkbox

Tags: javascript

I have a table that has a header with a checkbox in that row. The data gets dynamically added in the table with javascript. Now checking on the checkbox that is in the header row checks or unchecks all the checkboxes of all rows.. I have done it till here in the method **"checkUncheck()"**, i.e.:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkAppId" onclick="checkUncheck()"/>
```

But now, suppose there are 10 records dynamically added in the table. I have checked the main checkbox in the header. After that, I uncheck one of the checkboxes, e.g.: on the 10th row, then the checkbox of the header must be unchecked....and if I check all of the 10 rows of checkboxes manually, then the checkbox of main header must be checked. This is something normally observed in Yahoo, gmail, etc...

One way would be to count the number of checked ones and compare it with the total number of rows, and if found equal, then check the main one; otherwise, uncheck the main one. But I can't figure out where to do that... not working!

**Update**

```
<html>
<head><title>Checkbox puzzle</title></head>

<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkAppId" onclick="checkUncheck()"/>Main<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkAppId1" onclick="check()"/>chk1<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkAppId2" onclick="check()"/>chk2<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkAppId3" onclick="check()"/>chk3<br/>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkUncheck()
    {
        var totalRows = 4;
        if(document.getElementById("chkAppId").checked){
            checkedAll = true;
        }
        else{
            checkedAll = false;
        }

        for(i = 1; i< totalRows; i++){
            document.getElementById("chkAppId"+i).checked = checkedAll;
        }
    }


    function check()
    {
        var totalRows = 4,count=0;
        for(i = 1; i< totalRows; i++)   {
            if(document.getElementById("chkAppId"+i).checked){
                count= count+1;
            }
        }
        if(count ==totalRows - 1){
            //alert("check Main");
            document.getElementById("chkAppId").checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //alert("uncheck Main");
            document.getElementById("chkAppId").checked = false;
        }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This would be a simpler version that can explain the purpose, for anyone else who may need to implement such things.

Answer (score 0):

When you dynamically insert the checkboxes, do you give them each different IDs?

Post the code you have and someone may be able to help you.

Comment: yes I do...append that with a value that is the primary key of the record.. thanx i got it done...just the innerHtml and swing made it confusing...

Comment: on all the checkoxes of the records that are dynamically added, i just called a function that simply counted the total number of checked checkboxes. If that was equal to the total rows of the table, then it checked the main chkbox, otherwise uncheck it...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a self-contained example with 'dynamic' rows.

```
<HTML>

<input type="button" value="add row" onclick="add_row()">

<table border id="my_table">
<TR><TH><input type="checkbox" onclick="header_check_click()" id="header_check"></TH><TH>HEADER</TH></TR>
</table>

<FORM name="frm">

<script language="javascript">

var g_check_ids = [];

function header_check_click()
{
    var header_check = document.getElementById("header_check");
    for (var k in g_check_ids)
    {
        var the_check = document.getElementById("check" + g_check_ids[k]);
        the_check.checked = header_check.checked;
    }
}

function fix_header_checkbox()
{   
    var all_checked  = true;

    for (var k in g_check_ids)
    {
        var the_check = document.getElementById("check" + g_check_ids[k]);

        if (!the_check.checked)
        {   all_checked  = false;
        }
    }

    var header_check = document.getElementById("header_check");
    header_check.checked = all_checked;
}

function add_row()
{   
    var tbl = document.getElementById("my_table");
    var cnt = tbl.rows.length;
    var row = tbl.insertRow(cnt);

    var checkCell = row.insertCell(0);
    checkCell.innerHTML = "<input onclick=\"fix_header_checkbox()\" type=\"checkbox\" id=check" + cnt + ">";

    g_check_ids.push(cnt);

    var txtCell = row.insertCell(1);
    txtCell.innerHTML = "Cell " + cnt;
    fix_header_checkbox();
}
add_row();

</script>
</FORM>
</HTML>
```